# Design time: How to assign to multiple Swing Controls the same event?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, events

I have 10 JSliders, 10 JLabels and 10 JToggleButtons.
When the user drag a slider, i need to update its corresponding label and move to the same value all the sliders with the corresponding button toggled.
Now, my problem is not how to do this, but instead how to have this all in the same event.

In my good ol' VB days ( ;) ) i'd just have to assing the sliders with the same name, and so the buttons and the labels, and i'd have automagically arrays of sliders, labels and buttons accessible by the index, all firing the same event.

In my current C++Builder days, i have to set the Tag property (a generic int property) for each of them, select all the sliders and declare the same event for them all, then get back the tag from the sender object and use it as an index.
I'll then declare an array of Labels and Buttons pointers, so i can access the control by the index.

In Java, how can i set the same event for all my sliders in the IDE (i use NetBeans)?
And how can i access the labels and the togglebuttons as an array?

I've seens some example but they all are building controls at runtime, i want to design my form this way, instead.

Thanks

Comment: Using appropriate MVC, this should be no problem: 1 class to handle the view (toggle button, label, slider), 1 controller class that loads your model and initiate the views, 1 class (or more) to manage a model which will basically store the state of the slider, the toggle button and label. You add appropriate get/set on your models and fire events to notify the views, the views register themselves on the model and the controller performs the update of the model. Basic MVC...

Comment: I would like so much to understand what you're saying here...
Any chance to see some code to explain it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so really fast, here is roughly what I had in mind (can be very much improved, used some shortcuts to do it faster):

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TestMVC {

    public static class ModelObject {
        private PropertyChangeSupport pcs;

        public ModelObject() {
            pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        }

        public PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChangeSupport() {
            return pcs;
        }
    }

    public static class Model extends ModelObject {

        private List<Item> items;

        public Model() {
            items = new ArrayList<TestMVC.Item>();
        }

        public List<Item> getItems() {
            return items;
        }

        public void addToItems(Item item) {
            item.setModel(this);
            items.add(item);
            getPropertyChangeSupport().firePropertyChange("item", null, item);
        }

        public void removeFromItems(Item item) {
            items.add(item);
            item.setModel(null);
            getPropertyChangeSupport().firePropertyChange("item", item, null);
        }

    }

    public static class Item extends ModelObject {
        public static final String VALUE = "value";

        public static final String LABEL = "label";

        public static final String ENABLED = "enabled";

        private Model model;

        private boolean enabled;
        private String label;
        private int value;

        public Item() {
        }

        public Item(boolean enabled, String label, int value) {
            super();
            this.enabled = enabled;
            this.label = label;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Model getModel() {
            return model;
        }

        public void setModel(Model model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return enabled;
        }

        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            boolean old = this.enabled;
            this.enabled = enabled;
            getPropertyChangeSupport().firePropertyChange(ENABLED, old, enabled);
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setLabel(String label) {
            String old = this.label;
            this.label = label;
            getPropertyChangeSupport().firePropertyChange(LABEL, old, enabled);
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            _internalSetValue(value);
            if (this.isEnabled()) {
                for (Item item : model.getItems()) {
                    if (item != this && item.isEnabled()) {
                        item._internalSetValue(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void _internalSetValue(int value) {
            int old = this.value;
            this.value = value;
            getPropertyChangeSupport().firePropertyChange(VALUE, old, value);
        }
    }

    public static class ItemView implements PropertyChangeListener {
        private Item item;

        private JLabel label;
        private JSlider slider;
        private AbstractButton button;

        public ItemView(Item item) {
            super();
            this.label = new JLabel(item.getLabel());
            this.slider = new JSlider(0, 100);
            this.slider.setValue(item.getValue());
            this.slider.setEnabled(item.isEnabled());
            this.button = new JCheckBox((String) null, item.isEnabled());
            this.item = item;
            item.getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        }

        public JLabel getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public JSlider getSlider() {
            return slider;
        }

        public AbstractButton getButton() {
            return button;
        }

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(Item.LABEL)) {
                label.setText(item.getLabel());
            } else if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(Item.ENABLED)) {
                button.setSelected(item.isEnabled());
                slider.setEnabled(item.isEnabled());
            } else if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(Item.VALUE)) {
                slider.setValue(item.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    private Model model;

    public TestMVC(Model model) {
        super();
        this.model = model;
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestMVC.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gbc3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc3.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc3.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc3.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        for (final Item item : model.getItems()) {
            final ItemView view = new ItemView(item);
            view.getButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    item.setEnabled(view.getButton().isSelected());
                }
            });
            view.getSlider().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    item.setValue(view.getSlider().getValue());
                }
            });
            panel.add(view.getButton(), gbc1);
            panel.add(view.getLabel(), gbc1);
            panel.add(view.getSlider(), gbc3);
        }
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Model loadModel() {
        Random random = new Random();
        Model model = new Model();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Item item = new Item(random.nextBoolean(), "Some label " + random.nextLong(), random.nextInt(100));
            model.addToItems(item);
        }
        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Model model = loadModel();
                new TestMVC(model).initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`ChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) to each of your sliders. The listener should have a collection of all the other sliders it needs to update.

Something along these lines;

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
  JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
  int val = (int)source.getValue();

  for (JSlider slider : otherSliders) {
    slider.setValue(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you're telling me to write this code 10 times, one for each slider ChangeEvent (or at least to call a function like this 10 times).... which is exactly what i don't want to do.
And:
How about updating the label "related" to the source slider?
How about add a check to see if the togglebutton related to the slider in the for loop is toggled to see if i have to change it's value?
I need a way to know that "source" slider is the "third from the top", and so update the "third from the top" label and check the "third from the top" togglebutton....

Sorry for have not been clear in my question.

Comment: @FabioCalzolari You write this code once, in a class that implements `ChangeListener`. You then add that change listener to all your sliders. I'm sure you can figure out the rest about updating labels and checking buttons, it doesn't sound too hard. Have a go and if you're still stuck ask another question.